# My daily 'WTF'...Is something shady going on here - or would someone actually think all the answers were wrong?

Tags: discussion

I'm baffled as to what just happened with this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849114/c-what-means-being-immutable/6849156#6849156). I believe several of us gave adequate answers. All of a sudden, we all have been down-voted except for a couple at the top. Is someone trying to game some rep; is it malicious???

**Edit**
I normally wouldn't even care about being down-voted (especially when your answer is compared to an article written by Eric Lippert), but there were 3 of our answers (similar in description and quality) down-voted very rapidly. It just seems like someone was being mischievous.

**Edit #2**
Yes, it is likely someone actually thought all the answers were incorrect.

Comment: Looks like 3 answers were downvoted exactly once. All it means is that someone doesn't like your answer.

Comment: @Siva: some unscrupulous users have downvoted other answers to increase visibility of their own answer. It's not exact, but it's one method of gaming for rep.

Comment: @IAbstract maybe someone just thought the answers were wrong. (It could be strategic downvoting as well, but the two are impossible to tell apart)

Comment: @Siva Some take the rep system as a game and they want to "win", they even can engage in irregular behavior. How? Maybe an answerer downvotes competing answers, or maybe an answerer complains about 3 answers being downvoted by a conspirator, one of those 3 answers being his own.

Comment: Although I fail to see how @Marcelo's 2nd example is meaningful, if not accusatory. Regardless, my inquiry is valid. I hadn't seen this happen before - 3 correct answers being down-voted in rapid fashion.

Comment: @IAbstract Maybe it hasn't happened to you, but I bet that even you have downvoted 3 answers before in a same question.

Comment: @Marcelo: I can confidently state that I have never down-voted 3 correct answers in a given question. Otherwise, I don't believe I have ever down-voted more than 2 answers to a questions.

Comment: @IAbstract I didn't say correct answers, but since you have down-voted 2 answers, do you think it's possible that someone down-votes 3 answers if that someone thinks that they are incorrect?

Comment: Ach, anonymous downvotes on seemingly correct posts have generally only a countereffect: the post gets sympathy upvotes. It gives the anonymous downvoter something to think twice about.

Comment: @Pekka: dude, close that laptop and continue partying in the sun!

Comment: @Chichiray that's the plan :) Later!

Comment: Some users do not like the answers which are nearly the same or even alike.I had this issue with my answer which was nearly equal to the accepted answer [an answer to Linq to SQL 'Select Where' Problem (WPF C# 4.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678464/linq-to-sql-select-where-problem-wpf-c-4-0/6678581#6678581).there were many comments under it by me and Mr.Hilgarth but somebody obviously deleted them all.

Comment: -1 tired of people coming on Meta to whine about downvotes (There, I left a comment. *Are you happy?*)

Comment: @Cody: sure ...but, quite frankly, I prefer a simple down-vote than the additional, inflammatory comments.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say the three answers were similar in content and quality. So if someone though that the content was wrong or the quality was not good enough it's only logical if he downvoted all three of those answers.

So that seems perfectly normal. It would be much stranger if only one or two of the answers would have been downvoted.

Comment: Other answers of similar quality were not down-voted either. I am beginning to see the point @Pekka made in suggesting that someone thought the answers were incorrect. These were the first 3 answers given - all down-voted.